# Instantiate class using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, dll, interface, .net-assembly

I have different class libraries that each implement an interface `IImportCharacter`. In my main app, the user selects a DLL and the app needs to check if the library implements the interface and then instantiate the class in the library which implements it. I'm trying to use reflection to do this but I keep getting:

> Unable to cast object of type 'CustomCharacter.Ogre' to type
>   'MainGame.IImportCharacter'.

```
Assembly assembly = assemblyPath;
foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
{
    IImportCharacter instance = null;
    if (type.GetInterface("IImportCharacter") != null)
    {
        //exception thrown at this line
        instance = (IImportCharacter)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    }
}
```

I've copied the same `IImportCharacter` file into the main project, otherwise the compiler complains it doesn't know what `IImportCharacter` is. I think this might be causing the problem since it's not the same one being dynamically loaded. How can I fix this?

Comment: did you make sure that IImportCharacter is resolvable by the AssemblyResolver, i.e. present in AppDomain, Path, GAC etc? as an aside - if you are using .net 4 and above, use MEF. you will wonder MS didnt introduce this earlier

Comment: You can't create an instance of an interface. You need to have a class to create an instance.

Comment: Will something like this Help in this Link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32828/Using-Reflection-to-load-unreferenced-assemblies-a
or http://www.csharp-examples.net/reflection-examples/

Comment: Try passing typeof(IImportCharacter).FullName instead of the "IImportCharacter" into the .GetInterface() method.

Comment: @Krishna It's resolvable. I'll take a look at MEF but it might be overkill (haven't seen it yet though) @Joel Problem is I don't know the name of the class and therefore can't cast the `CreateInstance` to the right type. Is there a way of getting this? @DJ Can't see anything in those links that will help here I'm afraid. @Dmitry No error is thrown, but the line is never reached so it's just returning NULL.

Comment: It sounds like the Ogre class does not implement this particular interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I think the interface you're casting to is a different type with the same name. Why don't you move IImportCharacter to a shared assembly that you can reference both from your code and the one you're loading, since it's your interface?

Otherwise, try using `Convert.ChangeType()` with the dynamically loaded interface on your dynamically loaded type.

Comment: I tried the convert method but there's an exception that says `Object must implement IConvertible.` I'll try the shared assembly method, but would rather avoid having an extra assembly if possible.

Comment: I think that's much cleaner anyway if you want to be able to use the interface natively. Otherwise, you'll only be able to call the interface through reflection as well, which would be a lot more hassle. It's a good practice to separate your interface and your implementations anyway. It means you can write code directly against the interface methods but still swap in implementations at runtime via reflection.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use a shared assembly for this.